# Realize for loops in Java Stream for Array List?

Tags: java, oop, java-stream

Question : Can i realize method `private void fillingArrayList()` use Java Stream API (that is in one line) . The variable `i` is needed to define a length of String ;
I try a for each loop but it doesn't work . I need a range for loop.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Tolls {
    public static String digitsConcatenation(short number, long times) {
        return StringUtils.repeat(Character.forDigit(number, 10), Long.valueOf(times).intValue());
    }
}
```

```
public class Progression {
    public Progression(Digit digit) {
        this.digit = digit;
        this.numbers = new ArrayList<>(Long.valueOf(digit.getTimes()).intValue());
        this.fillingArrayList();
    }

    public Optional<Long> getProgressionSum() {
        return this.numbers.stream().reduce(Long::sum);
    }


    public List<Long> getNumbers() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.numbers);
    }

    private void fillingArrayList() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= digit.getTimes(); i++)
            this.numbers.add(Long.valueOf(Tolls.digitsConcatenation(digit.getNumber(), i)));
    }

    private final List<Long> numbers;
    private final Digit digit;
}
```

My Try :

```
 private void fillingArrayList() {
        Arrays.stream(this.numbers.toArray())
                .forEach(i-> this.numbers.add(
                        Long.valueOf(Tolls.digitsConcatenation(
                                digit.getNumber(), (Long) i))));
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work:

```
  IntStream.rangeClosed(1, digit.getTimes()).forEach(i -> this.numbers.add(Long.valueOf(Tolls.digitsConcatenation(digit.getNumber(), i))););
```

Comment: yes. Working , but LongStream, Thank you .

Comment: @andriy-byte if the answer is the correct one for you then you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some weird things in your code, like in `Progression`’s constructor, writing an expression like `Long.valueOf(digit.getTimes()).intValue()` instead of just `digit.getTimes()`. The con­struc­tor of `ArrayList` expects an `int` and `digit.getTimes()` returns an `int` (or a type implicitly con­vertible to `int`), as demonstrated with the loop condition `i <= digit.getTimes()`.

Likewise, the expression `Long.valueOf(times).intValue()` within the `digitsConcatenation` method, which is a cast from `long` to `int` in disguise, is only necessary because you declared the second parameter of `digitsConcatenation` as `long` despite you actually need an `int` and the caller’s argument is an `int`, so you could declare it as `int` in the first place.

But the entire approach of using string concatenation (incorporating a 3rd party library) and parsing it back into a number is unnecessarily complicated and inefficient. Since both conversions are implicitly using the decimal system, the operation’s result is the same as multiplying the number with ten and adding the value of the digit.

So you could just use

```java
private void fillingArrayList() {
    int n = digit.getNumber();
    LongStream.iterate(n, current -> current * 10 + n)
        .limit(digit.getTimes()).forEach(numbers::add);
}
```

without any string operation.

Even better would be to change the constructor to

```java
public Progression(Digit digit) {
    this.digit = digit;
    int n = digit.getNumber();
    this.numbers = LongStream.iterate(n, current -> current * 10 + n)
        .limit(digit.getTimes()).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

letting the stream produce the `List<Long>` instead of constructing it manually and modify it after construction.